# Kotlin inc() operator overloading

Tags: kotlin

I have a little problem to overload `inc()` operator, precisely to make a postfix and a prefix one.

Here my data class

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val name: String, var age: Int) {

    operator fun inc(): Person {
        val tmp = this
        this.age++;
        return tmp
    }
}
```

With this, *age* change before returning so it's only working for prefix version.

How can I do a postfix version of `inc()` operator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inc` is expected to return a new, incremented instance of the class. Since you've got a dataclass, we can use [Kotlin's convenience functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html#copying) that work on dataclasses to get a new instance for you relatively effortlessly.

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val name: String, var age: Int) {
  operator fun inc(): Person =
    this.copy(age = this.age + 1)
}
```

`Person.copy` is one of several dataclass methods generated for you. It takes the same arguments as your primary constructor, with each argument defaulting to the current value on `this` (i.e. any arguments not passed will be the same as the corresponding values on `this`). So by passing *only* the `age` parameter by name, we modify only the one we want to and leave the others untouched.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you’re trying to do. You are breaking the contract that the increment operator must not mutate the class. It must return a new instance of the class.